# Function to Run every 30 days

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks

Web application will be on shared hosting, so I won't have any access to the root of the server. I am using `Asp.net MVC5 (C#)` and `SQL Server 2012` for this web app. I want to run a function or task to run every 30 days to delete some records for SQL table before a specific date. I want to know what is the best solution for the shared hosting.

1. Windows Task Scheduler
2. Windows Service
3. SQL Jobs
4. Somthing like Jeff Atwood proposed using cookies [in this article](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/)
5. Schedule Table (to check executed date in global.asax Application_Start and call a function)

I am looking for a solution which is better for shared hosting.
Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the SQL server Agent? This would be the best solution.

Comment: Does normal shared hosting offer SQL server agent, No, I don't think I have the access. Any other suggestion please

Comment: @ArbazAbid, I agree with Peter Smith, sql job - is the best way here. Explore possibilities of your sql server.

Comment: best in terms of what? Performance, ease of implementation?

Comment: Actually web app is on shared hosting and shared hosting generally have limited accessibility. So we can't create SQL Job. Best term means which is actually effective for shared hosting. Please read my question again. Thanks

Comment: I use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to run scheduled tasks inside ASP.NET; it has a lot of features for a lightweight solution and is very easy to use and get up and running with. You can run inside your existing web app or have it as a separate application.

Comment: @AnishPatel: I will check it, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open source port of the Java quartz library called [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net) showing how to use it with ASP.NET.

You might also want to check out [Running Background Tasks in ASP.NET](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) by Scott Hanselman for a comparison of the available solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will check it out now.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is really working on shared hosting environment. God bless!

Answer (score 3):

I have use [HangFire](http://hangfire.io) several times is an great solution, I believe is the way to go.

However if you run in to some problems with it, it also possible to use a service [like](https://www.cronasaservice.com) this.

As recommended by [Arbaz Abid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1655774/arbaz-abid) you can also use [quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it now and will mark as answered soon.

Comment: @dnligmz: HangFire is also a great solution for shared hosting environment, but quartz.net is a easy solution. Thanks again for your suggestion.